# Do not let user install specific component, if another is already installed

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Very new to InnoSetup, but I could not find any documentation on this. I would like to implement a condition where if the user has already installed a specific component, it will not allow them to install another specific component.

For example: If Bob has previously installed ComponentA, and ties to install ComponentB, it will error our with a warning "Cannot install ComponentB while ComponentA currently installed"

This is what I have come up with so far:

```cpp
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
    Value: string;
    UninstallKey: string;
begin
    UninstallKey := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' +
        ExpandConstant('{#SetupSetting("AppId")}') + '_is1';
    Result := (RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, UninstallKey, 'Inno Setup: Selected Components', Value) or
        RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, UninstallKey, 'Inno Setup: Selected Components', Value)) and (Value <> '');   
    if CurPageID  = wpSelectComponents then
        if Result = WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[1] then
        begin
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[1] := False;
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[1] := True;
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[2] := False;
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[2] := False;
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[3] := False;
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.Enabled[3] := True;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I know I do not quite have the Registry Query exactly right for selected components.. I feel like I'm close though.  The problem is, Result may have multiple components in it. like (apple,orange,mango) but I want the statement to still be true if just "mango" exists.

Comment: Inno stores info about installed components in it's uninstall key in Registry. You can read that info during the installation and then disable specific component via Code section.

Comment: Thank you, I made an edit based on your recommendation. I am not sure if the line: `if Result = WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[1] then` is correct though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Think you could do this in another way:

Use Flags:
 `exclusive`

example:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "connect"; Description: "Mainsection"; Types: "full" ;Flags: fixed
Name: "connect\compA"; Description: "ComponentA"; Types: "full"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "connect\compB"; Description: "ComponentB"; Flags: exclusive

[Files]
Source: "srcpath"; DestDir: "dirpath"; Components: connect\compA
Source: "srcpath"; DestDir: "dirpath"; Components: connect\compB
```

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKNH.png)

So if "Bob" wants to choose componenB he can not use ComponentA without automatic deselect componentB

So now if "Bob" already installed ComponentA and wants to install ComponentB and u dont want that both components are installed u need to use `installdelete`

example:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "dirpath\compA"; Components: connect\compB;
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "dirpath\compB"; Components: connect\compA;
```

I hope this will help